# In Rails how do I use link_to with google maps to create a clickable link?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am testing with a rails page where I do search on filters that retrieve different rooms. Now the room's infoWindow only show the price but that is not what I need to do.

I want to make the code in the infoWindow clickable to take me to that rooms page. How can I do that?

this is my java script code

```
var marker, inforwindow;

        <% @arrRooms.each do |room| %>
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: <%= room.latitude %>, lng: <%= room.longitude %>},
            map: map
          });

          inforwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<div class='map_price'>$ " + <%=room.price%> + "</div>"


          });
          inforwindow.open(map, marker);
        <% end %>
```

It tried different ways to include link_to but I cannot figure out how to get the implementation correct.

Assistance and guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using ERB within a javascript segment, use the `escape_javascript` helper: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Example:

```
var marker, inforwindow, windowContent;

<% @arrRooms.each do |room| %>
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: <%= room.latitude %>, lng: <%= room.longitude %>},
    map: map
  });

  windowContent = "<div class='map_price'>$<%= escape_javascript room.price %></div>";
  windowContent += "<div><%= escape_javascript link_to('Room Details', room) %></div>";

  inforwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: windowContent
  });
  inforwindow.open(map, marker);
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sean thank you so much on answering my cry for help! your code works but there was a small tweek as I had to remove escape_javascript from the first windowContent var assignment so it was:

  windowContent = "<div class='map_price'>$<%= room.price %></div>";

And it worked perfectly

Comment: I have a follow up question on advancing my code to utilize AJAX within JS to avoid boring reloads... I placed the code here https://gist.github.com/albaqawi/62c36de64c3e51b21edceb1f8b78fd4d
between lines 14 - 30 is my For loop the focus of my question. How can write this line #23 in a more robust way to avoid server paths like localhost? my code works well no dev box. that is why I love using built in helpers like link_to

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't need to hardcode a URL like that. Since you're using ERB you can use `link_to` and path helpers. For example: `windowContent += "<%= link_to(room.listing_name, room_path(room) %>";`. Substitute `room_path` for whatever the path helper is for your show listing route.

Comment: hi Sean even after adding a ) to do minor correction ... I get the following error: undefined local variable or method `room' for #<#<Class:0x007f9322bd2e20>:0x007f93237e75a8>
Did you mean?  room_url
               room_path
               rooms_url
               @rooms ......... any thoughts? I do love to make it dynamic but don't seem to happen.

Comment: How about you accept this answer and ask a separate STO question (send me the link) and post your new code. I'm thinking your either using the wrong helper or your calling it outside your `@arrRooms.each` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can this work?

```
    <% @arrRooms.each do |room| %>
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: <%= room.latitude %>, lng: <%= room.longitude %>},
        map: map
      });

      inforwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div class='map_price'>$ " + <%=room.price%> + "</div><a href='"+ <%= room_path(room) %> +"'></a>"


      });
      inforwindow.open(map, marker);
    <% end %>
```

Comment: sadly no even thought it sounds so right, I even tried it before and nothing appears not even google map

Answer (score -1):

You can try!

var marker, inforwindow;

```
    <% @arrRooms.each do |room| %>
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: <%= room.latitude %>, lng: <%= room.longitude %>},
        map: map
      });

      inforwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<a href=/rooms/"+room.id+">" + <%=room.price%> + "</a>"


      });
      inforwindow.open(map, marker);
    <% end %>
```